# How to handle display none and block for a View component using react native

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native

> In my scenario there are two Views.
>   While load the component i need to none second view after while click
>   on TextInput need to open the second view after selecting the value
>   from the second view selected value should be populate in the first
>   view  TextInput after that secondView should be closed.I can acheieve
>   the same effect using react.js but the same effect i am unable to do
>   using react native .

```
var ViewDisplay = React.createClass({
   componentDidMount(){
       this.refs.secondView.getDOMNode().style.display="none";
   },
   clickHandler:function(){
         this.refs.secondView.getDOMNode().style.display="block";
   },
   populateValue:function(){
        this.refs.secondView.getDOMNode().style.display="none"; 
   },
   render:function(){
     return(<View>           
             <View  ref={firstView}>
                      <TextInput style={styles.textInput} placeholder=  {enter value} onEndEditing={this.clickHandler}/>
             </View>
            <View ref={secondView}>
               <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="#ffa456" onPress={this.populateValue}> 
                    <Text ref={key}>first</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
              <TouchableHighlight  underlayColor="#ffa456" onPress={this.populatevalue}>   
                 <Text>Second</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
              <TouchableHighlight  underlayColor="#ffa456" onPress={this.populatevalue}>  
                 <Text>third</Text>
             </TouchableHighlight>
           </View>
       </View>)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a flag in your component state with the click handler, then use that to determine which view should be rendered

```
render() !this.state.clicked ? <View ref={firstView}> ... </View> : <View ref={secondView}> ... </View>
```